# Cors issue using NodeJs, Express and React locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cors

Im building a small application with NodeJs and Express for the backend and React for the client side.

To avoid CORS policy issues i'm using the "cors" npm package, but it's not solving my issue on the client side....

Express:

```
const express = require('express')
const routes = require('../routes')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')

const server = express()

server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
server.use(express.json())
server.use(cors())
server.use('/api', routes)

module.exports = server
```

Client side:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Contacts = () => {
    const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('localhost:3300/api/contacts/')
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Contacts list</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Contacts
```

And i still get that on the console:

[image]

Am i missing something here?

Thank you by advance...

Comment: Put 'http://' in front of 'localhost:3300...'

Comment: As the error says you need to use one of the allowed schemes, ie you need the scheme prefix like `http://` in your url for your get() call

Answer (score 1):

Put 'http://' in front of 'localhost:3300...'

Comment: This is the correct answer. You were missing the protocol. localhost is also just a mask for 127.0.0.1. So you may have some internal mapping problem for your hosts. But this answer should receive the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

you need to fix your server side code to allow cross domain requests

```
server.use(cors())
server.options('*', cors());
```

Comment: Asterisk is not necessary if you want to enable ALL CORS REQUESTS, see first usage example here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally i replace

```
axios.get('localhost:3300/api/contacts/')
```

by

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3300/api/contacts/')
```

and it work...